# PHP post data to login to external webpage

Tags: php

There is an external website i want to be able to login to from my website. the external website has this HTML:

```
<form action="/Login" method="post">


            <div style="width: 280px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 150px; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;" class="ui-corner-all">
                <div class="pw-input-group">
                    <span class="pw-input-group-addon">
                        <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>
                    </span>
                    <input id="username" name="username" class="required text pw-form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username" minlength="2" maxlength="45" />
                </div>
                <div class="pw-input-group">
                    <span class="pw-input-group-addon">
                        <i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i>
                    </span>
                    <input id="password" name="password" class="required text pw-form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" minlength="2" maxlength="45" />
                </div>
                <div style="float: right;">
                    <input id="loginbutton" name="submit" style="line-height: 1.42857; padding: 6px 12px; font-size: 14px; color: #555;" type="submit" value="Login" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

I have tried using this PHP code on my site:

```
//set POST variables
$url = 'https://portal.external-website.co.uk/Login';
$fields = array(
                'username' => urlencode("username"), 
                'password' => urlencode("password"), 
                'submit' => 'Login'
                );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) {
    $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
}
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//we need to ignore SSL errors here
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);
echo curl_getinfo($ch) . '<br/>';
echo curl_errno($ch) . '<br/>';
echo curl_error($ch) . '<br/>';

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

It shows

```
bool(true) Array
0
```

but when i visit the website again, its telling me im not logged in

how can i get this to log me in?

Comment: You do not login your client but your server. You cannot be logged in on next visit from your browser...

Comment: Furthermore: `foreach($fields as $key=>$value) {
    $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
}
rtrim($fields_string, '&');` is just the same as `http_build_query($fields_string);`. `rtrim` has a return value and does not edit the variable directly. You have to reassign it.

Comment: i am then trying to access content from a page that can only be seen when logged in, for this i use `file_get_contents('url.com');` - when i do a `var_dump` of this it just shows me the login page for the external website

Comment: Yes, this is the normal behaviour of a page with a login ;-) You should read about cURL options (like cookie saving) to realize this. It is not a huge problem.

Comment: What's the best way to use curl to login to an external website so I can view the content of the members pages?

Comment: As I said before. There is no best method for using cURL, there is just one method.

Comment: So how can I use curl to login and then be able to view the content of a page?

Comment: Use a (temp) file and specify it as `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` in your cURL requests. Then the session is passed.

Comment: I don't suppose you can add to my code please, sorry I'm new to curl

Answer (score -1):

There's a good chance the external website is keeping track of your logged-in state by placing a cookie, to store either a session reference or a token. Such a cookie can't be set when you're posting from someplace else than a browser.

Comment: If you really want, you can set a `cookiejar` and transfer it to your local machine :D

Comment: Things could get quite ugly :p

Answer (score -1):

Based on your comments, this should be the solution for fetching a page after logging in:

```
$cookieFile = tempnam(__DIR__, "");
$loginUrl = 'https://portal.external-website.co.uk/Login';

$fields = array(
    'username' => "username", 
    'password' => "password", 
    'submit' => 'Login',
);
$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$fetchUrl = "https://portal.external-website.co.uk/Profile/123";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $fetchUrl);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch); // This should be the sites content
curl_close($ch);

unlink($cookieFile);
```

Comment: i have done a `var_dump($result);` before the `curl_close` and all that is showing is `string(0) ""`

Comment: @charlie: Which `$result`? The first or the second?

Comment: both are displaying the same thing

Comment: If it is a public site, you can post the URL here, then I can debug it easier.

Comment: Now it works: You have to set `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);`.

Comment: what part do i add that in?

Comment: I have edited my post. Where the other `curl_setopt` are.

Comment: ok, now doing a `var_dump` on the second `$result` just returns `bool(false)`

Comment: Correct URL? Try to get a page where you can see if you are logged in.

Comment: ah - incorrect URL. I have just changed the URL and the `var_dump` is showing me the login page

Comment: What is the content after first request?

Comment: its showing the content of the website but its as if i am not logged in

Comment: On the page, I mean. It just shows you the login page again after the first cURL request?